# Exception doesn't need to be thrown to be caught, but IOException does

Tags: java, exception, throws

Why does the following code compile fine, but the method being called does not need to throw `Exception`? Isn't `Exception` a checked exception and not an unchecked exception? Please clarify.

```
class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            amethod();
            System.out.println("try ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("catch ");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("finally ");
        }
        System.out.print("out ");
    }
    public static void amethod() { }
}
```

If I want to use a try catch with `IOexception` (a checked exception), the method being called needs to throw `IOException`. I get this.

```
import java.io.IOException;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            amethod();
            System.out.println("try ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("catch ");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("finally ");
        }
        System.out.print("out ");
    }
    public static void amethod() throws IOException { }
}
```

Comment: I think your understanding is backwards.  The `throws` declaration is intended to list the checked Exceptions that will be thrown by the callee, not those that will be caught by the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't 'Exception' a checked exception and not an unchecked exception?

Yes, it is.

But even if we know the method doesn't throw `Exception` itself, the code `catch(Exception e){` could still execute.  The code in the `try` block could still throw something that inherits from `Exception`.  That includes `RuntimeException` and its subclasses, which are unchecked.

`catch(IOException e){`, on the other hand, can only catch checked exceptions.  (Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so anything that's a subclass of `IOException` can't possibly be a subclass of `RuntimeException`.)  The compiler can fairly easily figure out that none of the code in the `try` block can possibly throw an `IOException` (since any method throwing a checked exception must explicitly say so) which allows it to flag the code.

Comment: perfect! easy to understand

Comment: Actually, this answer is misleading and even wrong. The point that `Exception` doesn't need to be thrown, in order to be caught, and why such code compiles, while other checked exceptions *must be* thrown to be caught, comes from special treatment of `java.lang.Exception` class. `try` block can be absolutely empty (and in this case, there is no chance that something will be thrown), but you will still be able to `catch(Exception e) {..}`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes, the compiler gives it special treatment. But *why* does the compiler give it that special treatment? Pretty sure it's because of what I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there would be a compiler error for having a `try` block that never throws a checked exception that you have a `catch` block for, but the behavior you're observing comes from the fact that the Java Language Specification treats `Exception` specially in this circumstance. According to  [§11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause *can catch* checked exception class E<sub>1</sub> and it is not the case that the `try` block corresponding to the `catch` clause *can throw* a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E<sub>1</sub>, unless E<sub>1</sub> is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

This is reasonable because `Exception` (and its superclass `Throwable`) can be used to catch exceptions that extend `RuntimeException` also. Since runtime exceptions are always possible, the compiler always allows `Exception` to appear in a `catch` clause regardless of the presence of checked exceptions.

Comment: No, I respectfully disagree.

Comment: "Why does the following code compile fine, but the method being called does not need to throw Exception?" it is simply because, as was pointed out in the accepted answer,  if one calls a method, inside a try catch, that method being called does not need to be throwing anything.

Comment: @HellishHeat No, that’s not the reason. As explained in my answer, normally when catching a checked exception, there ***must*** be at least one method inside the try block which throws that checked exception or else it’s a compile-time error, but the compiler rule does not apply to the `Exception` class or it’s superclasses.

Comment: @HellishHeat If you remove `throws IOException` from the second code sample in the OP’s question, there will be a compiler error.

Comment: quite right; I just tested that and indeed you're right. learn-something-new-today box ticked.

Comment: I have bookmarked this page and I'll return tomorrow to undo my downvote. Sorry.

Comment: @HellishHeat I’m glad I could clarify that. I made an edit so you can remove your downvote.